# Multiple group_left join to get owner labels

Tags: prometheus, promql

We are trying to set up a prometheus alert on kube_pod_status_phase metrics, but we want some ownership labels, I have managed to get the one level of ownership from kube_pod_owner, but then we would need the labels from kube_replicaset_owner as well.. If you see the below query we do get the info from both kube_pod_status_phase and kube_pod_owner. How would we take this in step further to also get the owner_name from kube_replicaset_owner, which is the deployment name, what we are looking for is to have the deployment name, and not only the pod name.

```
sum by(namespace, pod, owner_kind) 
(max by(namespace, pod) 
(kube_pod_status_phase{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace="itops",phase=~"Pending|Unknown|Failed"})
* on(namespace, pod) 
group_left(owner_kind) topk by(namespace, pod) (1, max by(namespace, pod, owner_kind) 
(kube_pod_owner{owner_kind='ReplicaSet'})))
```